# Remove Ubuntu from dual boot Windows 8 PC

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

I have recently upgraded to Windows 8 and want to remove my Ubuntu OS. It was installed using a bootable pen drive. I tried deleting Ubuntu partition but after that the screen remained blank. I had to reinstall Ubuntu to get rid of that.